# Wirecloud authentication using keystone only?

Tags: django, fiware, fiware-wirecloud

The [instructions](https://wirecloud.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation_guide/#integration-with-the-idm-ge) for providing FIWARE based authentication for Wirecloud suggest installing KeyRock (a frontend/backend combo of the Horizon/Keystone GE). Is the frontend (Horizon) really necessary if the only application to be secured is a Wirecloud instance (and possibly some backend services). The point is to avoid, *if possible*, to have to configure/style/maintain etc. a second frontend. Is it possible to authenticate directly using a Django plugin like [this](https://github.com/openstack/django_openstack_auth)? Pros and cons?

Answer (score 1):

WireCloud is currently linked to the use of `django.contrib.auth`, any authentication plugin based on it should work. Moreover, the instructions for using KeyRock are using `python-social-auth` so, in fact, you can use it for authenticating using any of [the backends supported by `python-social-auth`](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/intro.html#auth-providers): GitHub, Twitter, OpenId, ...

In that regard, I don't see any problem in the use of the plugin you are proposing (Although I have not tested it).

The advantage of using the KeyRock backend provided by WireCloud is that it enables operators and widgets to propagate the credentials to third-party services using KeyRock for authentication (e.g. Orion Context Broker, Object Storage, ... and in general, any service behind a PEP proxy).